# How to find cause of IIS shutting down an app pool after only a minute or so

Tags: iis, .net-5, application-pool

We have a .Net 5 web app we just launched recently.  In the event log I'm seeing that the application pool keeps shutting down and restarting after anywhere from 30 seconds to a minute or so.  I have no idea why and can only find one other warning in the event log.  I don't know if it's related or not.  It says Failed to determine the https port for redirect.  I've looked this up and supposedly [this was supposed to fix it](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/failed-to-determine-the-https-port-for-the-redirect/), but it hasn't.  Here are some of the events I'm seeing.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:30:48 PM
Event ID:      1033
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1033</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:30:48.929881200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22032</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 123656.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:30:18 PM
Event ID:      1032
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1032</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:30:18.976727300Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22030</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 123656.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:28:34 PM
Event ID:      1032
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1032</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:28:34.377273900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22027</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 56952.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:28:00 PM
Event ID:      1033
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1033</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:28:00.341568600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22026</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 145204.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:27:18 PM
Event ID:      1032
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1032</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:27:18.529768200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22024</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 145204.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:27:01 PM
Event ID:      1033
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1033</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:27:01.337341700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22023</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 118920.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:26:26 PM
Event ID:      1032
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1032</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:26:26.338518200Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22021</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 118920.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:26:00 PM
Event ID:      1033
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1033</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:26:00.021186600Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22020</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/EMPLOYEES' has shutdown.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 62004.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Log Name:      Application
Source:        IIS AspNetCore Module V2
Date:          7/18/2023 2:25:15 PM
Event ID:      1032
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG
Description:
Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="IIS AspNetCore Module V2" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1032</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-07-18T18:25:15.489575000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>22016</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>EC2AMAZ-D7E2JAG</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Production\employees\' started successfully.</Data>
    <Data>Process Id: 62004.</Data>
    <Data>File Version: 15.0.22105.17. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 02c6de4ba6022025fcda7581415f310f8c73cdc3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: How busy is this server? If there isn’t much traffic, IIS/ANCM tends to shut down unnecessary processes.

Comment: It's relatively busy and that's part of the problem.  Our users are running into a lot of problems because they'll be in the middle of doing something and the site shuts down, they submit a form, and then it forces the site to come back up which can take a good 20 or more seconds to respond.

Comment: Based on the source code of ANCM itself, https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.17/src/Servers/IIS/AspNetCoreModuleV2/InProcessRequestHandler/inprocessapplication.cpp#L337 this shutdown log entry `ASPNETCORE_EVENT_APP_SHUTDOWN_SUCCESSFUL_MSG` is harmless. Every time a managed thread exits, an entry is written to Windows event log. So, **it does not indicate application pool shutdown** and the problems your users experienced should be caused by something else. Besides, .NET 5 reached end of life a while ago.

Comment: The warning you mentioned "failed to determine the https port for redirect" may not be related to application pool restart issue, it may be caused by misconfiguration in IIS or issue with HTTPS binding settings. Situations that can cause an application pool to be restarted/reset or even shut down include: stack overflow exceptions, out of memory exceptions, any unhandled exceptions that cause a thread to crash, etc.

Comment: same problem from yesterday. any solution ?

Comment: No solution yet.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description. Debug Diagnostics Tool (DebugDiag) maybe can be a lifesaver. It can create and analyze IIS crash dumps. IIS Application Pool Crash and Debug Diag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/parvez/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag When the server hangs, crashes or performance is low, it is usually necessary to grab the server's thread stack (Thread Dump) for subsequent analysis. So I suggest you open a case to get further support via https://support.microsoft.com.